# Java, force implementation of method without knowing parameters

Tags: java, overriding

I have an abstract class that performs basic operations, now I want to force every derived class to have a method "check", but the point is I know nothing about this method. For example, the abstract class:

```
public abstract class Service<T extends Transport> {

  public T getTransport(int id) { 
    [...] 
  }

  public abstract boolean checkTransport(T transport, ...);

}
```

and two implementing classes:

```
public ServiceAAA extends Service<ClassA> {

  public boolean checkTransport(ClassA t) {
    [...]
  }

}

public ServiceBBB extends Service<ClassB> {

  public boolean checkTransport(ClassB t, Integer value, Integer otherValue) {
    [...]
  }

}
```

The ServiceBBB needs two parameter to check the object t of class ClassB. 
Of course it's not working, is there a way to force the subclass to implement the checkTransport method without using the "Object ... " notation?

Comment: No, and if you use varargs you'll be just hacking a bad design into working (or at least compiling).

Comment: Could you give some explanation _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: I want to force the implementer to write a checkTransport method. Of course my approach is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

Let's pretend there *were* a way. How would you invoke this method, either from the abstract Service class, or from any call site that had a reference to this object typed as `Service<...>`? There'd be no way of knowing what the specific subclass's method expects, and thus no way of invoking the method.

One way around this is to pass the checker in as a class to Service; that is, to use composition instead of inheritance. If you do that, you can have the checker's interface take no extra arguments at all (a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) might work, for instance), and the specific subclasses that implement that checker could have the arguments passed at construction time.